# Convert JS function to jQuery - (input field clear default value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onsubmit

I was wondering if some jQuery expert would be so kind to convert the below script to jQuery. I am having trouble converting it myself and would much prefer to use a jQuery equivalent.

What I am trying to do is simply remove the default value of 'Search' from a keyword field onSubmit, as the user can leave the keyword field blank.

```
function clearValue() {
    var searchValue = document.getElementById("global-search").value;
    if (searchValue == "Search") {
        document.getElementById("global-search").value = "";
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: Wow... that was quick. Thanks guys!

Comment: What happens if I want to search for the word *Search* ?

Comment: That is a good point... it may be a silly idea to disallow that keyword. I am stuggling to make this form fool proof, and may decide to absolutley position the input labal instead of using a default value.

Comment: You could consider [Placeholder Text](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) and fall back to label positioning if necessary, or simply don't do the placeholder for browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//wait for the DOM to be ready (basically make sure the form is available)
$(function () {

    //bind a `submit` event handler to all `form` elements
    //you can specify an ID with `#some-id` or a class with `.some-class` if you want to only bind to a/some form(s)
    $('form').on('submit', function () {

        //cache the `#global-search` element
        var $search = $('#global-search');

        //see if the `#global-search` element's value is equal to 'Search', if so then set it to a blank string
        if ($search.val() == 'Search') {
            $search.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

Here is the documentation related to this answer:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val
- `document.ready`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- jQuery Selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: A useful comparison of event handlers in jQuery http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: I only skimmed the post but it looked to be good information. Don't use `.live()` though. It's depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 and it's functionality is the same as using `.delegate()`.

Comment: Yes, that's mentioned as one of the _cons_ for .live() :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#global-search").val() == "Search")
    $("#global-search").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearValue() {
    if ($("#global-search").val() == "Search") {
        $("#global-search").val('');
    }
}
```